# Combining Spray Routing + Actor Pattern Matching

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-cluster

Following the Akka Cluster documentation, I have the Worker Dial-in example running.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/cluster-usage.html

So I've trying to integrate that with a spray routing.

My idea is to have a cluster behind the scenes and through a http rest, call that service.

So I have the following code.

```
object Boot extends App {

  val port = if (args.isEmpty) "0" else args(0)
  val config =
    ConfigFactory
      .parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=$port")
      .withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.cluster.roles = [frontend]"))
      .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load())

  val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)
  val frontend = system.actorOf(Props[TransformationFrontend], name = "frontend")
  implicit val actSystem = ActorSystem()

  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(frontend, interface = config.getString("http.interface"), port = config.getInt("http.port"))
}

class TransformationFrontend extends Actor {

  var backends = IndexedSeq.empty[ActorRef]
  var jobCounter = 0
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case _: Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)

    case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/job"), _, _, _) =>

      jobCounter += 1
      val backend = backends(jobCounter % backends.size)

      val originalSender = sender()

      val future : Future[TransformationResult] = (backend ? new TransformationJob(jobCounter + "-job")).mapTo[TransformationResult]
      future onComplete {
        case Success(s) =>
          println("received from backend: " + s.text)
          originalSender ! s.text
        case Failure(f) => println("error found: " + f.getMessage)
      }

    case job: TransformationJob if backends.isEmpty =>
      sender() ! JobFailed("Service unavailable, try again later", job)

    case job: TransformationJob =>
      jobCounter += 1
      backends(jobCounter % backends.size) forward job

    case BackendRegistration if !backends.contains(sender()) =>
      println("backend registered")
      context watch sender()
      backends = backends :+ sender()

    case Terminated(a) =>
      backends = backends.filterNot(_ == a)
  }
}
```

But what I really want to do is to combining the spray routing with those pattern matching.

Instead of writing my GET like the above, I would like to write like this:

```
path("job") {
  get {
    respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
      complete {
        (backend ? new TransformationJob(jobCounter + "-job")).mapTo[TransformationResult]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But extending my Actor with this class, I have to do the following

```
def receive = runRoute(defaultRoute)
```

How can I combine this approach with my TransformationFrontend Actor pattern matching methods? BackendRegistration, Terminated, TransformationJob?

Comment: How about forwarding your Spray requests to another actor which has the logic for doing pattern matching. If you can pass the requestContext in the message so that you can complete the HTTP request from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compose `PartialFunction`s like `Receive` with `PartialFunction.orElse`:

```
class TransformationFrontend extends Actor {
  // ...
  def myReceive: Receive = {
    case job: TransformationJob => // ...
    // ...
  }
  def defaultRoute: Route =
    get {
      // ...
    }
  override def receive: Receive = runRoute(defaultRoute) orElse myReceive
}
```

That said, it often makes sense to split up functionality into several actors (as suggested in the comment above) if possible.

Comment: Great, I was so focused trying to mixing both together that I would never think of split the receive methods. Thank you.